# FOSHttpCacheBundle cache invalidation with Symfony built-in reverse proxy doesn't work

Tags: symfony, caching, cache-invalidation, foshttpcachebundle

I'm trying to do a hard thing: implementing cache invalidation with Symfony 4.4.13 using FOSHttpCacheBundle 2.9.0 and built-in Symfony reverse proxy.
Unfortunately, I can't use other caching solution (like Varnish or Nginx) because my hosting service doesn't offer them. So, the Symfony built-in reverse proxy is the only solution I have.

I've installed and configured FOSHttpCacheBundle (following the [documentation](https://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/invalidation.html)). Also created a CacheKernel class and modified Kernel to use it (following [Symfony official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/http_cache.html), [FOSHttpCache documentation](https://foshttpcache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/symfony-cache-configuration.html) and [FOSHttpCacheBundle documentation](https://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/symfony-http-cache.html)).

After few tests (with my browser), the HTTP caching works and GET responses are cached (seen in browser network analyzer). But, when I update a resource with PUT/PATCH/POST, the GET responses still come from the cache and are unchanged until the expiration. My deduction is the invalidation doesn't work.

Have I do something wrong? Can you help me to troubleshoot?
See my code and configuration below.

config/packages/fos_http_cache.yaml

```
fos_http_cache:
    cache_control:
        rules:
            -
                match:
                    path: ^/
                headers:
                    cache_control:
                        public: true
                        max_age: 15
                        s_maxage: 30
                    etag: "strong"
    cache_manager:
        enabled: true
    invalidation:
        enabled: true
    proxy_client:
        symfony:
            tags_header: My-Cache-Tags
            tags_method: TAGPURGE
            header_length: 1234
            purge_method: PURGE
            use_kernel_dispatcher: true
```

src/CacheKernel.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\CacheInvalidation;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\CustomTtlListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\DebugListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\EventDispatchingHttpCache;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\PurgeListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\RefreshListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\UserContextListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\Store;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class CacheKernel extends HttpCache implements CacheInvalidation
{
    use EventDispatchingHttpCache;

    // Overwrite constructor to register event listeners for FOSHttpCache.
    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $kernel, SurrogateInterface $surrogate = null, array $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($kernel, new Store($kernel->getCacheDir()), $surrogate, $options);

        $this->addSubscriber(new CustomTtlListener());
        $this->addSubscriber(new PurgeListener());
        $this->addSubscriber(new RefreshListener());
        $this->addSubscriber(new UserContextListener());
        if (isset($options['debug']) && $options['debug'])
            $this->addSubscriber(new DebugListener());
    }

    // Made public to allow event listeners to do refresh operations.
    public function fetch(Request $request, $catch = false)
    {
        return parent::fetch($request, $catch);
    }
}
```

src/Kernel.php

```
<?php
namespace App;

use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\HttpCacheAware;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\HttpCacheProvider;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements HttpCacheProvider
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;
    use HttpCacheAware;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    public function __construct(string $environment, bool $debug)
    {
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
        $this->setHttpCache(new CacheKernel($this));
    }
...
```

public/index.php

```
<?php
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

...

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$kernel = $kernel->getHttpCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

One of mine controller, src/Controller/SectionController.php (NOTE: routes are defined in YAML files)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Section;
use App\Entity\SectionCollection;
use App\Form\SectionType;
use FOS\HttpCacheBundle\Configuration\InvalidateRoute;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class SectionController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    /**
     * List all sections.
     *
     * @Rest\View
     * @param Request $request the request object
     * @return array
     *
     * Route: get_sections
     */
    public function getSectionsAction(Request $request)
    {
        return new SectionCollection($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Section::class)->findAll());
    }

    /**
     * Get a single section.
     *
     * @Rest\View
     * @param Request $request the request object
     * @param int     $id      the section id
     * @return array
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException when section not exist
     *
     * Route: get_section
     */
    public function getSectionAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if (!$section = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Section::class)->find($id))
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Section does not exist.');

        return array('section' => $section);
    }

    /**
     * Get friends of the section's user.
     *
     * @Rest\View
     * @return array
     *
     * Route: get_friendlysections
     */
    public function getFriendlysectionsAction()
    {
        return $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getSection()->getMyFriends();
    }

    private function processForm(Request $request, Section $section)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $statusCode = $em->contains($section) ? Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT : Response::HTTP_CREATED;

        $form = $this->createForm(SectionType::class, $section, array('method' => $request->getMethod()));
        // If PATCH method, don't clear missing data.
        $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()), $request->getMethod() === 'PATCH' ? false : true);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($section);
            $em->flush();

            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode($statusCode);

            // set the 'Location' header only when creating new resources
            if ($statusCode === Response::HTTP_CREATED) {
                $response->headers->set('Location',
                    $this->generateUrl(
                        'get_section', array('id' => $section->getId()),
                        true // absolute
                    )
                );
            }

            return $response;
        }

        return View::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    /**
     *
     * Creates a new section from the submitted data.
     *
     * @Rest\View
     * @return FormTypeInterface[]
     *
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_friendlysections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_sections")
     *
     * Route: post_section
     */
    public function postSectionsAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->processForm($request, new Section());
    }

    /**
     * Update existing section from the submitted data.
     *
     * @Rest\View
     * @param int     $id      the section id
     * @return FormTypeInterface[]
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException when section not exist
     *
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_friendlysections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_sections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_section", params={"id" = {"expression"="id"}})")
     *
     * Route: put_section
     */
    public function putSectionsAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if (!$section = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Section::class)->find($id))
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Section does not exist.');

        return $this->processForm($request, $section);
    }

    /**
     * Partially update existing section from the submitted data.
     *
     * @Rest\View
     * @param int     $id      the section id
     * @return FormTypeInterface[]
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException when section not exist
     *
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_friendlysections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_sections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_section", params={"id" = {"expression"="id"}})")
     *
     * Route: patch_section
     */
    public function patchSectionsAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return $this->putSectionsAction($request, $id);
    }

    /**
     * Remove a section.
     *
     * @Rest\View(statusCode=204)
     * @param int     $id      the section id
     * @return View
     *
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_friendlysections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_sections")
     * @InvalidateRoute("get_section", params={"id" = {"expression"="id"}})")
     *
     * Route: delete_section
     */
    public function deleteSectionsAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if ($section = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Section::class)->find($id)) {
            $em->remove($section);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching few days, I found the solution by myself.

In `CacheKernel`, I extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache` as described in FOSHttpCache documentation. But, the class must extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache` instead as described in Symfony documentation. By consequences, the constructor change too.

To be honest, I don't know the difference between these two classes but you must use the second one if you want to have a built-in functional reverse proxy. It works now for me.

I put here the final code of src/CacheKernel.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\CacheInvalidation;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\CustomTtlListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\DebugListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\EventDispatchingHttpCache;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\PurgeListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\RefreshListener;
use FOS\HttpCache\SymfonyCache\UserContextListener;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class CacheKernel extends HttpCache implements CacheInvalidation
{
    use EventDispatchingHttpCache;

    /**
     * Overwrite constructor to register event listeners for FOSHttpCache.
     */
    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        parent::__construct($kernel, $kernel->getCacheDir());

        $this->addSubscriber(new CustomTtlListener());
        $this->addSubscriber(new PurgeListener());
        $this->addSubscriber(new RefreshListener());
        $this->addSubscriber(new UserContextListener());
        if (isset($options['debug']) && $options['debug'])
            $this->addSubscriber(new DebugListener());
    }

    /**
     * Made public to allow event listeners to do refresh operations.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function fetch(Request $request, $catch = false)
    {
        return parent::fetch($request, $catch);
    }
}
```

The rest of the code don't change.

Hope it helps. See you.